# Show sql server queries

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, profiler

I know how to see queries executed in mysql but is there such a thing for sql server express?

My mvc application is executing queries and in the sql server management studio 2016 I can choose tools => SQL server profiler.

Start a profile and see absolutely nothing happen when my mvc application executes queries.

Is there a free product for this? Googling for this gives me very confusing suggestions and many are not free but it is suggested the profiler can show queries that have been executed and much more.

Comment: [You can try this one](https://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/)

Comment: You should use SQL Server Profiler, but need to make a few settings in order to see the queries. You need to set the instance (database server) which you want to trace. If you have a single database on your instance then that should be fine. If you have multiple users running queries then you should filter based on `SPID` column I believe it's called, to see only your queries. This should be under Tools -> Preferences. Also, this is most important **you need to check the T-SQL** section to choose which events you want to track. Otherwise, you won't see any SQL being picked up

Comment: Are you using entity framework ?

Comment: @Symeon Yes, wanted to see what the app was doing since I didn't write it, the code has no comments and the database has no comments either. So what the data in the columns mean can only be guessed from how the application retrieves it and how the result is presented.

Answer (score 0):

I used a different connection string in my project than the one used in the profiler. Stopping sql server express and my app still running revealed that the app was not using sql server express but (I think) sql server desktop edition.

For sql server express the connection string needs to be something like:

```
Data Source=COMPUTER_NAME\SQLEXPRESS;...
```

For sql server desktop (or whatever the one with visual studio is called)

```
Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;....
```

Comment: Thats localdb - you can still connect to that using SSMS .  Are you saying that you can now do the profile ok?  if not the alternative is to put tracing into the app - EF allows you to do this and lists each sql statement created by EF

Comment: @Symeon Thank you for your response. I can do the profile now. Have to profile the same sql instance that the application uses.